# detecting duplicate string in a explode function php

Tags: php

how do i detect duplicate string inside explode?

```
$str = 'a, b, c, a, a, a, b, e, w, r, d, o'; // example str
$explode = explode(',', $str);
```

any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$explode = explode(',',$str);
$unique = array_unique($explode);
if(sizeof($explode) != sizeof($unique)){
    echo "There are duplicates";
}else{
    echo "No duplicates";
}
```

I suggest using `explode(', ',$str);`  so you can avoid all those extra spaces

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`array_unique()`](http://www.php.net/array_unique)

but be wary of the spaces: they will be part of each array element if you use `explode()`. If you enter an extra space somewhere, `array_unique` won't detect the duplicate any more.

Use the second example in the manual page on [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/trim) to shave off the spaces before doing the `array_unique()` for a more reliable comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(array_unique(str_getcsv($str)));
```